Deleting agents from anylogic
I want to delete agents that are occupying some resources. If I delete them with the function agent.deleteSelf, would the resources that are occupyed by them be released?

Yes. Same if you delete them with a Sink or via the remove_MyAgentType(...) calls.
Java is quite good at removing unused resources so typically no need to do garbage collection these days.
Keep you model tidy, destroy unused agents and you are good :)
